# php with ioncube given error /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: undefined symbol: _empty_map

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, freeradius, ioncube

I have installed freeradius with radius manager on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic i686) with php version PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.48 with Suhosin-Patch configured.

Everything installs perfectly but when I try to access php pages it gives error HTTP ERROR 500 in browser.

When I check apache2 logs it gives output:

```
Failed loading /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: undefined symbol: _empty_map
[Thu Jan 25 03:28:27 2024] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.48 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

php -v output:

```
Failed loading /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: undefined symbol: _empty_map
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.48 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct 14 2020 14:45:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Please help out to sort this issue.

I have tried reinstalling and also updating php and and ioncube, installation of ioncube agian, but the same result.

Comment: Everything you've mentioned is _wildly_ outdated and out of support. The chances that you're looking at documentation that is relevant to versions that old is very slim, as are the chances that you're getting packages of the correct versions. LTS is not forever.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in ioncube 13.0.2 (and possibly other 13.x versions) for PHP 5.3. It's fixed but no new release yet. Beta is available:

https://www.ioncube.com/beta/phpd-13.0.2_p1-libs-linux_x86_64-glibc2.4.tgz